# What is the easiest way to simulate 100 different browsers connections?

Tags: testing, browser

I have a website that I want to conduct testing on. All you need to do is to go to homepage and enter given password. Unfortunately, I can only open one instance in one browser(have no idea what it uses, probably cookies). If I open second tab in the same browser it just redirects me to the same screen as first tab. The question is: How can I simulate 100 broswers connection (Is there any addons or something else, so the application would not treat different tabs as the same browser or something?)

Comment: Just so you know, this is called [load testing](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=load+test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Apache's ab (Apache benchmark) tool. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html
Example:
ab -c 10 -n 1000 http://www.yourdomain.com/mypage.jsp

This keeps sending 10 concurrent requests (-c 10) until 1000 http-requests (-n 1000) have been sent.

Option -A allows you to send authentication credentials.